# jgit how can i get all the commits that occurred between two dates

Tags: git, jgit

Or just all the commits that occurred between two dates?  In SVN, you could do something like `svn diff -r{date}:{date}` to do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take example of this [JGit test class `RevWalkFilterTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalkFilterTest.java#L292):

```
Date since = getClock();
Date until = getClock();
RevFilter between = CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since, until);
```

It uses the class [`org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.filter.CommitTimeRevFilter`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/filter/CommitTimeRevFilter.java).