# How do I use filters in jGit?

Tags: java, jgit

How do I use `RevFilter`s in jGit?

I found an answer to a question I had about completing a particular task ([getting the commits made between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580762/jgit-how-can-i-get-all-the-commits-that-occurred-between-two-dates)), and the answer said to use a particular subclass of `RevFilter`. However, I don't know how to use `RevFilter`s!

In particular, I would like to know what I need to do to take the answer in the question I linked to, which says

> ```
> Date since = getClock();
> Date until = getClock();
> RevFilter between = CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since, until);
> ```

And use it to actually iterate over the commits between the two dates. Something like:

```
RevFilter between = CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since, until);
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
walk.magicallyApplyFilters(between);
for(RevCommit commit : RevWalk) {
    // Do my thing
}
```

I have read the jGit documentation. Sadly, [in the section that would show how to use filters](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#RevWalk), there is the line:

> TODO talk about filters

So the documentation does not help me. And although I get the impression that using filters is a basic part of using jGit, nobody else has asked how to use them on StackOverflow yet!

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the source, all you need to do is create an instance of the `RevWalk` iterator, set the filter, then iterate over the walker.

```
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD)));
walk.sort(RevSort.REVERSE); // chronological order
final LocalDate thisYear = new LocalDate(2015, 1, 1); // joda
walk.setRevFilter(CommitTimeRevFilter.after(thisYear.toDate()));
for(RevCommit commit : walk) {
    // do your thing
}
```

The filter is essentially just a predicate on whether or not a commit is yielded from the walker.  There are a number of filters that you could use found in the `org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.filter` package.  Or you can create your own by extending the `RevFilter` class.

Comment: I'm having problems using your answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056917/when-i-use-a-revfilter-my-revwalk-isnt-selecting-any-commits

Comment: I'm trying it out right now. But so far, my impressions are that the time that jgit goes by is not exactly the same time that you set. Like there's a significant offset. In my tests, the repo I'm looking at has revisions since the beginning of 2014. Trying to set a filter for revisions in 2015 is yielding commits as of 2014-12-15 to now. Something seems off.

Comment: Oh, I figured out my issues, I was confusing myself with author commit times with revision commit times.  The revision commit times are appearing in the correct times, I was just having issues converting the time to a human readable date.