# When I use a RevFilter, my RevWalk isn't selecting any commits

Tags: java, jgit

I'm using jGit to walk over the commits in a repository. When I use the `RevWalk` class by itself, I get back all of the commits in the repository. When I use `revWalk.setFilter()` to add a filter, though, I no longer get any commits whatsoever, even though I know for sure that commits exist that match my filter's criteria.

Here is my code:

```
   RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
   // These two lines give me trouble:
   // RevFilter filter = CommitTimeRevFilter.between(sinceDate, untilDate);
   // walk.setRevFilter(filter);

    Ref head = repo.getRef("refs/heads/master");
    RevCommit headCommit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
    // omitting some exception handling for conciseness
    walk.markStart(headCommit);

    List<MyCommitPOCO> commits  = new LinkedList<>();

    for(RevCommit commit : walk) {
        MyCommitPOCO processedCommit = processRevCommit(commit);
        commits.add(processedCommit);
    }

    walk.dispose();

    return commits;
```

When I run this code without the two lines that are commented out at the top, the for loop iterating over `walk`'s commits processes every commit in my repository, which I expected. When I uncomment the lines with the `RevFilter`, however, the for loop does not iterate over even a single commit, which doesn't seem right to me. I've tried running the program with multiple values for `sinceDate` and `untilDate` that I know are appropriate for the repository I'm trying to work with, but none of the attempts I've made have worked.

Why isn't my `RevWalk` letting me iterate over any commits when I use a `RevFilter` with it? What's wrong with the two lines of code that cause the problem when I uncomment them?

Answer (score 0):

I found the `CommitTimeRevFilter` to work as expected. Have you debugged your code to see that the desired commits arrive at the filter code?

Below is a test that might serve as a starting point. It does four commits with timestamps of 1, 2, 3, 4 second and then uses a RevWalk with a time-filter to collect those between second 2 and 3:

```
public class RevWalkFilterLearningTest {

  @Rule
  public final TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  private Git git;

  @Test
  public void testTimeFilter() throws Exception {
    commit( 1000 );
    commit( 2000 );
    commit( 3000 );
    commit( 4000 );
    RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( git.getRepository() );
    RevFilter filter = CommitTimeRevFilter.between( new Date( 2000 ), new Date( 3000 ) );
    revWalk.setRevFilter( filter );
    Ref headRef = git.getRepository().getRef( Constants.HEAD );
    RevCommit headCommit = revWalk.parseCommit( headRef.getObjectId() );
    revWalk.markStart( headCommit );

    int count = 0;
    for( RevCommit revCommit : revWalk ) {
      count++;
    }

    assertEquals( 2, count );
  }

  private void commit( int time ) throws Exception {
    PersonIdent committer = new PersonIdent( "committer", "committer@example.com" );
    git.commit().setCommitter( new PersonIdent( committer, new Date( time ) ) ).setMessage( "msg" ).call();
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws GitAPIException {
    git = Git.init().setDirectory( tempFolder.getRoot() ).call();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    git.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question. The `CommitTimeRevFilter` isn't working as I expect it to in my code, even if it is for yours. How does your answer help me diagnose my problem?

Comment: It was meant as a starting point that you might gradually alter to match your code and maybe find the problem along the way. If that doesn't work for you, can you provide more information how the commits are created or what timestamps they have? Did you debug the filter and see if it is called and what it does?