# JGit: Filter Revwalk using between and fetch a TreeWalk for the result

Tags: java, jgit

I basically want to filter my TreeWalk month-wise. Below is the code i have used to do so:

```
head = repository.getRef("HEAD");
walk = new RevWalk(repository);

Date since= new Date();
since.setMonth(02);
since.setYear(2014-1900);
since.setDate(01);

Date until= new Date();
until.setMonth(02);
until.setYear(2014-1900);
until.setDate(31);

RevFilter between = CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since,until);
walk.setRevFilter(between);

commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
tree = commit.getTree();

TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
treeWalk.addTree(tree);
treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
TreeFilter treefilter= walk.getTreeFilter();
treeWalk.setFilter();
return treeWalk;
```

I am filtering the RevWalk first and then, i fetch a TreeWalk because I ultimately need a treewalk for a month to fetch my details from it.

Problem is, even after filtering i am getting the head (last commit). I am sure the problem is

```
commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
```

But i am not sure how to fix it to get a filtered TreeWalk for a month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (I got the inspiration to solve this in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993763/4997684):

```
final RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);

Date since= new Date();
since.setMonth(02);
since.setYear(2014-1900);
since.setDate(01);

Date until= new Date();
until.setMonth(02);
until.setYear(2014-1900);
until.setDate(31);

RevFilter between = CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since, until);

walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD)));
walk.sort(RevSort.REVERSE);
walk.setRevFilter(between);

for(RevCommit revCommit : walk) {
    System.out.println(new Date((long) revCommit.getCommitTime()*1000L));
}
```